# Read and print out the dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: java

I am really new to Java, and I am writing a Java program that reads dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy and prints out the date in the format  day, year. The program must verify that the year is between 1900 and 2014 (both limits included) and that the day and month and year are valid and mutually consistent. If the input is incorrect, the program must display an appropriate message and terminate. If the input is correct, the output should be printed in the specified format.

For Example:
Enter Date
04/30/2013
April 30, 2013

Enter Date
01/12/1888
Year should be between 1900 and 2014

I am stuck at how to limit the year and days (like February only has 28), and how to print out like the examples above. I am suppose to use if else and switch statement for this problem. Here is the code i got so far, and thanks for your help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Dates {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int month, day, year;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter Date in The Format mm/dd/yyyy : ");
    month = input.nextInt();
    day = input.nextInt();
    year = input.nextInt();
    String months = "January February March April May June July August "
            + "September October November December";
    String January = months.substring(0,7);
    String February = months.substring(8,16);
    String March = months.substring(17,22);
    String April = months.substring(23,28);
    String May = months.substring(29,32);
    String June = months.substring(33,37);
    String July = months.substring(38,42);
    String August = months.substring(43,49);
    String September = months.substring(50,59);
    String October = months.substring(60,67);
    String November = months.substring(68,76);
    String December = months.substring(77,85);
    if (month == 1) {
        months = January;
        day = 31;
    }
    else if (month == 2) {
        months = February;
        day = 28;
    }
    else if (month == 3) {
        months = March;
        day = 31;
    }
    else if (month == 4) {
        months = April;
        day = 30;
    }
    else if (month == 5) {
        months = May;
        day = 31;
    }
    else if (month == 6) {
        months = June;
        day = 30;
    }
    else if (month == 7) {
        months = July;
        day = 31;
    }
    else if (month == 8) {
        months = August;
        day = 31;
    }
    else if (month == 9) {
        months = September;
        day = 30;
    }
    else if (month == 10) {
        months = October;
        day = 31;
    }
    else if (month == 11) {
        months = November;
        day = 30;
    }
    else if (month == 12) {
        months = December;
        day = 31;
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("Invalid Month");
    }

    if (year >= 1900 || year <= 2014) {
        System.out.print(year);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Year should be between 1900 and 2014");
    }
    System.out.println(months + " " + day + ", " + year);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Take care when adding zeros at the left of a number, because Java will consider them as *octals*. In your case it doesn't affect the code because octal `01` is equal to `1` in decimal base. For example, `10 != 010`. Also, try using a `switch` statement rather than that `if-else if` structure.

Comment: you can assign the month value using `split(" ")` instead of `substring()`

Answer (score 8):

Use `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` for working and formatting dates respectively in Java. That's the good choice! Please don't reinvent the wheel unless you are in your learning process.

Please read the documentation of [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API

Comment: yeah, i know. I just helped him to go to the right path. Now, he learnt that it is difficult to write code to work on dates to cover all scenarios on his own. Instead he can make use of well tested, higly resourceful API from Java ;)

Comment: that's exactly what I mean. And It would be much better if you include the reference links too :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), and you can verify with a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should try using the classes [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **GregorianCalendar** for formatting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer would be more valuable if it was more elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to skip the  '/' character before reading another Integer.

```
/*month = input.nextInt();
day = input.nextInt();
year = input.nextInt();*/
String dummy = input.nextLine();
month = Integer.parseInt(dummy.substring(0, 2));
day = Integer.parseInt(dummy.substring(3, 5));
year = Integer.parseInt(dummy.substring(6, 10));
```

You last line is wrong

```
System.out.println(months + " " + day + ", " + year);
```

For Leap year stuff, you should visit the wiki.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm